# Why is my POST request returning 400? URL and JSON are validated as OK

Tags: java, apache, http, http-post

I have some code that is returning a 400 response code:

```
try {
        // Set the String Entity version of the JSON to be sent
        StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(payload1.toString());

        // Create HTTP Client
        HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();

        // Create Request Object
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(destination);
        post.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        post.setEntity(entity);

        // Execute the request
        System.out.println("Sending request...");
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);

        System.out.println(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
}
catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I know that payload1.toString() works, I have validated it as JSON with [this JSON validator](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/).  I also know that the request works with the endpoint, I sent the **payload1.toString()** to **destination** using [ApiRequest.io](https://apirequest.io/) and it popped up correctly on the other side.

Please help!! What am I missing?

Comment: Why don't you check the payload of the response to see if it give the reason there? Or look at the log file on the server.

Comment: Can you include the values of destination and payload1 in your post?

Comment: I can't unfortunately due to the nature of the code but I know that they are not the problem.

Comment: It just says "Bad Request"

Answer (score 0):

Request may be validated as json but having business logic problems. Try to send request using any rest client, for example postman.

Comment: The exact same JSON string being sent works perfectly fine with the same destination with ApiRequest.io

Comment: It's a chat app and the chat is popping up perfectly fine

Comment: Perhaps the payload are broken after some transformation before sending? .toString() - isn't overrided? 
Maybe try to send a hard-coded payload string? Just for test.